# How to get number of bytes?

Tags: java

How do I obtain the number of bytes before allocating the byte size of the array 'handsize' as shown below as the incoming ByteArray data are sent in 3 different sizes. Thanks.

```
BufferedInputStream bais = new  

BufferedInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream()); 

DataInputStream datainput = new DataInputStream(bais); 

//need to read the number of bytes here before proceeding.

byte[] handsize = new byte[bytesize];  

datainput.readFully(handsize);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), then you wouldn't have to worry about it.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//write data to output stream
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know how many bytes of data are yet to be received on a socket--knowing this would be tantamount to clairvoyance.  If you're using your own protocol for client/server communication, you could send the number of bytes of data as an integer, before sending the actual bytes themselves.  Then the receiving side would know how many bytes to expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have yet to try the ByteArrayOutPut stream, as for sending the number of bytes of data as an integer, that is what I am doing at the moment but I realised a problem in wihch the sender side is sending 3 different message structures of different byte sizes therefore, the data I received will be in a messed up state.

Comment: @k80sg: Just send the size before each of the structures. How would this be "messed up"? The receiver needs to know both the size and the content, so you may also need a value in the transmission indicating the type of structure.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the problem as stated is impossible. But why do you need to know? Why not store the data in a variable size structure, like an ArrayList, as you read it? Or maybe even process it as you read?